# More that one page in single screen view pager (Like CircleApp)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, geometry

I need to make the view pager as shown below[image]

the image in the middle.i have browse and come with some solution [cmmonsware multiple-view-viewpager-options](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html)

but it show more that three views  and i cant control the view style.like fade the views in left and right and show the middle page like this .I have googled but does not get any solution .Can any one help me to sort this problem by giving some  snippet or any clue how to solve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even my  question has down voted . i have find the solution  after a long research 
,So that am sharing my answer so that this will be help full for someone.

I have just followed this  code from git hub [SimpleInfiniteCarousel with Viewpager](https://github.com/mrleolink/SimpleInfiniteCarousel)

and meet my requirement The output  of this example  look like this

[image]

**Additional Data Adding**

Got Another Good example From [Android-ViewPager-Carousel-UI](https://github.com/44kksharma/Android-ViewPager-Carousel-UI)

Thank you :)